# The page 'MyCasePage' does not use the standard controller: Case, it uses: null

Tags: deployment, page-layout, inline-visualforce

I am deploying pages,Controllers,Pagelayout to production.

My Pagelayout of Case includes inline VF page 'MyCasePage' whose standard controller is Case. But still it gives following error while deployment

> The page 'MyCasePage' does not use the standard
>   controller: Case, it uses: null

Please help i need to deploy to production asap
Tia

Comment: Can you share the vf page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you are deploying, but try remove page layout from change set and then deploy, after this you can move page layout separately, hope this helps.